# Apache Beam seems to not be running the tests

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a set of tests that I have implemented on my code base that seems to not being executed and passing nevertheless. As a corollary, Jacoco code coverage is not reporting any execution for these test. This is an example of the problem.

```
package com.striiv.dataflow;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleTest {
    public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

    public static <T> DoFn<T, T> print(String label) {
        return new DoFn<T, T>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void print(ProcessContext ctx) {
                String message = ctx.element().toString();
                System.out.println(message);
                ctx.output(ctx.element());
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintFunctionDoesNotMutateData () {
        Object genericObject = new Object();
        PCollection<Object> collection = pipeline
                .apply(Create.of(genericObject).withCoder(AvroCoder.of(Object.class)))
                .apply(ParDo.of(print("Label")));

        PAssert.that(collection).empty();
        PAssert.that(collection).containsInAnyOrder(genericObject);
    }

}
```

This test should fail because the two assertions contradict each other.
What am I missing here?

Some info:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.16.0) (Gentoo icedtea-3.16.0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe its not just showing in the code snippet, but are you doing pipeline.run() in your code?

Comment: Oh... yes... I was missing the pipeline.run() . Thanks both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run it, you have to run it by `pipeline.run()`. Add it in your test method as the following and try again please.

```
    @Test
    public void testPrintFunctionDoesNotMutateData () {
        Object genericObject = new Object();
        PCollection<Object> collection = pipeline
                .apply(Create.of(genericObject).withCoder(AvroCoder.of(Object.class)))
                .apply(ParDo.of(print("Label")));

        PAssert.that(collection).empty();
        PAssert.that(collection).containsInAnyOrder(genericObject);

        pipeline.run();
    }
```